# OK to use same event listener in dom ready and window load for jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Ive used when a select list's option is changed as an event listener, with something like this:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
        functionToRun();
});
```

Is it OK to use the event listener more than once? So something like below. I know for this exact example it makes no sense, but for more complicated code with conditionals at work it would be easier for me to maintain my code if I used the event listener twice.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
        functionToRun();
});

//other code

$('#mySelect').change(function() {
        functionToRunTwo();
});
```

Also, I have some code that runs on dom ready and some that runs on window load. Is it OK to use the same event listener in both instances?

Comment: You do realise, you will be attaching the same handler twice. That should be done just once, and within the `ready` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work as expected: both event listeners will be fired and there is certainly no problem with that. From [`jQuery.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (which is called internally by `jQuery.change()`):

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event
>   type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers
>   registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were
>   bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the
>   normal event propagation path.

I am not sure if this answers your second question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but if you want to use the function depending on the context, make sure you unbind the function you don't need.